# JS optional chaining clarification

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, optional-chaining

I found a really great use case for optional chaining in my react project. I have used it slightly before but this line of code has made me a bit confused.

I have a table that is sortable.
One of the columns shows success or failure depending on if `failed_date` is null or a date.

```
sortedRows = sortedRows.sort((a, b) => a?.failed_date?.localeCompare(b?.failed_date));
```

But What confuses me is which value does the '?.' check is nullish?

Does `a.failed_date?.localeCompare()` check if `failed_date?.` is null/undefined or does it check if `?.localeCompare()` is null/undefined?

Same with `b?.failed_date` is it checking b to be nullish? or failed_date.

I think My confusion comes from looking at the [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Because `arr?.[50]` checks if element 50 is nullish but `obj.method?.()` checks if the method is not nullish?

Looking at this second block of code (which I believe is now correct) `a.failed_date` may be nullish and won't do localeCompare if `a.failed_date` is null?
But what if `a.failed_date` is not null but `b.failed_date` is null?
Does localeCompare not care? I haven't gotten an error but I was using `localeComapre(b?.failed_date)`

```
sortedRows = sortedRows.sort((a, b) => a.failed_date?.localeCompare(b.failed_date));
```

Comment: *"Because `arr?.[50]` checks if element 50 is nullish"*. No, it checks whether `arr` is nullish. `?.` always checks whether "the value before it" is null or undefined. But either way, the `sort` callback should always return a number and not `null`. You have to define some order for the elements if these objects are null or don't have that property.

Comment: You can check each of these cases in your browser console, one at a time, for a better understanding. Note: `obj.method?.()` and `obj?.method()` are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you define variable like below

```
const variable = { value: 'test' };
```

then you want to access `variable?.value` it equals `variable === null || variable === undefined ? undefined : variable.value`.

Same with array.

Check typescript playground and see js output https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDA2gXQNwBQBiyKA-AHRYCsADDkA

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the `?` in that context means *optional chaining*.

How it works is, for example, if you define an object like below, and you want to try and access the `views` property, it will throw an error.

```js
const obj = { website: "stackoverflow.com", };
console.log(obj.views.toFixed(0)); // Error!
```

This is because you are trying to access a method off of `undefined`, which doesn't have anything.

To avoid this error, we can use *optional chaining*, like below.

```js
const obj = { website: "stackoverflow.com", };
console.log(obj?.views?.toFixed(0)); // undefined
```

Optional chaining tells JavaScript to complete the method/read the key, but if it doesn't exist, instead of throwing an error, just return `undefined`.

---

It also works with arrays; the same way! If, say, index `78` doesn't exist, instead of throwing an error, it will just return `undefined`.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(arr?.[78]?.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate here, it is possible to stack multiple optional chaining operators as seen in OP's code `a?.failed_date?.localeCompare(b?.failed_date)`
In these cases, it is not a question of which object key value will be checked. The code will be evaluated from left to right and if any of the object values are nullish then undefined will be returned.

Refer to the documentation for further understanding
[MDN Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#stacking_the_optional_chaining_operator)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33371312)